# how to split data into minimum groups

Tags: algorithm

I wonder if where is an algorithm that can split some data into min groups.

It should looks like,
Precondition: The sum of some number of the data <= m, where m is a explicit number,
expect: Those data split into groups of min count.

Is there an algorithm or good idea?

Thanks.

Here is an example.

```
List<Integer> rawList = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 1, 2, 10, 5, 8, 3);
```

You can split them into 8 groups and each group contains 1 number,
which is not what I wanted.

```
Integer maxSum = 12; //Assume that one group can holds max sum of 12.
```

I need minimum groups, so the answer looks like

```
List<Integer> group1 = Arrays.asList(10, 2);
List<Integer> group2 = Arrays.asList(8, 3, 1);
List<Integer> group3 = Arrays.asList(5, 1, 1);
```

The example above only spent 3 groups to split the raw data.
Those 3 groups will be one answer.(There are others way to use min groups.)

It seems like similar to bin-packaging problem which @Dillon Davis mentioned. Only this one is easier, I think.

Ps. The answer requires minimum groups, time and space complexity is not the major problem.

Comment: Such that is minimises the number of groups? Because if I understand the question, each group could have 1 element and it would be a solution.

Comment: Please give a non-trivial example of input and output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem has strong resemblances to the bin-packing problem. The objective is to pack elements of various sizes into as few bins as possible, each with some fixed capacity. The general approach is to use a greedy algorithm to repeatedly try to pack either the largest element into the first bin it will fit into (first-fit), or to try to fit the largest element into the bin with the least space remaining possible (best-fit). Neither of these guarantee an optimal solution, but usually yield near-optimal results, which may be sufficient.